# clone bootcamp with windows 7 and install windows 8 then restore

Tags: backup, boot-camp, windows, windows-7, restore

I have mac mini (2012) in which i have installed mac os 10.8.2 and windows 7 using bootcamp. Now that i want to try windows 8 (as long as it can remain active). I decided to install windows 8 in same partition where windows 7 is installed. Basically what i am looking is:

1. Clone windows 7 and save as image
2. Install windows 8 on same partition clone and save as image. [I assume that it overwrites windows 7 and will allow to boot windows 8]

I would like to restore to either windows 7 or 8 when i need.

Note:
1. I can't triple boot to windows 7 and 8 which was my first choice 
2. I dont want to use virtual machine since i want to use windows for compilation

Comment: Although there may be some edge case tools that run on OS X, let's get this to the SuperUser group where windows backup and restore expertise is readily available. Feel free to edit this question if your requirement is to use non-windows tools and we can re-evaluate the migration if needed.

Comment: There is no reason your plan wouldn't work. Although I also see no reason a triple boot is out of the question. The simplest problem is if you can install the current version of Bootcamp in order to get the best possible Windows 8 support.  Just create an image, then upgrade the Windows 7 installation to Windows 8, should be dead simple.

Comment: @Ramhound i cant triple boot because i already have 4 partitions, Also windows 8 i may not be able to activate. so  mostly i would like to use it as long as it remains active.

Comment: @bmike i dont mind if i need to run tool in windows or mac, but i think that we need to do some thing inside mac...i am not sure though.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try sdomething like: http://sourceforge.net/projects/g4l/ ? This will clone for you whatever it's there on the drive if you can boot it off the USB.
I would recommend using GZIP for speed of cloning.

Comment: First, I am not sure if it can work for mac, second i dont have additional harddisk